# How to get mod_pagespeed to load and do stuff?

Tags: apache, mod-pagespeed

I've installed mod_pagespeed as per the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/download) on my Debian system, following the dpkg method.

When I run `a2enmod pagespeed`, it says `Module pagespeed already enabled`.  In /etc/apache2/modules-available, I can see pagespeed.conf, and pagespeed.load.  Links to those files are also present in mods-enabled.

However, `phpinfo()` and `apache_get_modules()` don't show a pagespeed module.  I can also see no difference in ouptut (minification, for example), or headers from the server.

I've tried this on an Apache 2.4 installation and on a separate system an Apache 2.2 installation.

What am I missing?